# i want to make a new variable that says shot1 shot2 shot3 so on and forth how do i do this?

Tags: vb.net

Here is what i have tried so far , but no new shot variable is being declared

```
Module Module1
    Dim shotlist As New List(Of Boolean)
    Dim shono As Integer = 0
    Dim shonos As String
    Dim shotname As String
    Dim fshot As Boolean
    Dim shots As String

    Sub Main()
        For i As Integer = 0 To 1000
            Dim ("shots" & i) as String = "shots" & i
            fshot = Convert.ToBoolean(shots)
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Not really too sure exactly what you're trying to do here.  Is it add a new "shot" to the shotlist variable?  What exactly do you expect Dim ("shots" & i) as String = "shots" & i to do?

Comment: What you want is an array

Comment: Or maybe a `Dictionary(Of String, Boolean)`, or a `List(Of (Shot as String, Value as Boolean))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do things this way. The variable names you see when you write a program are lost, turned into memory addresses by the compiler when it compiles your program. You cannot store any information using a variable's name - the name is just a reference for you, the programmer, during the time you write a program (design time)

Think of variables like buckets, with labels on the outside. Buckets only hold certain kinds of data inside

```
Dim shotname as String
```

This declares a bucket labelled `shotname` on the outside and it can hold a string inside. You can put a string inside it:

```
shotname = "Shot 1"
```

You can put any string you like inside this bucket, and thus anything you can reasonably represent as a string can also be put inside this bucket:

```
shotname = DateTime.Now.ToString()
```

This takes the current time and turns it into a string that looks like a date/time, and puts it in the bucket. The thing in the bucket is always a string, and lots of things (nearly anything actually) can be represented as a string, but we don't type all our buckets as strings because it isn't very useful - if you have two buckets that hold numbers for example, you *can* multiply  them:

```
Dim a as Integer
a=2
Dim b as Integer
b=3
Dim c as Integer
c=a*b
```

But you can't multiply strings, even if they're strings trust look like numbers; strings would have to be converted to numbers first. Storing everything as a string and converting it to some other type before working on it then converting it back to a string to store it would be very wearisome

So that's all well and good and solves the problem of storing varying information in the computer memory and giving it a name that you can reference it by, but it means the developer has to know all the info that will ever be entered into the program. `shotname` is just one bucket storing one bit of info. Sure you could have

```
Dim shotname1 as String
Dim shotname2 as String
Dim shotname3 as String
```

But it would be quite tedious copy paste exercise to do this for a thousand shotname, and after you've done it you have to refer to all of them individually using their full name. There isn't a way to dynamically refer to bucket labels when you write a program, so this won't work:

```
For i = 0 To 1000
  shotname&i = "This is shotname number " & i 
Next i
```

Remember, `shotname` is lost when compiling, and i is too, so `shotname&i` just flat out cannot work. Both these things become, in essence,  memory addresses that mean something to the compiler and you can't join two memory addresses together to get a third memory address that stores some data. They were only ever nice names for you to help you understand how to write the program, pick good names and and not get confused about what is what

Instead you need the mechanism that was invented to allow varying amounts of data not known at the design-time of the program - arrays

At their heart, arrays are what you're trying to do. You're trying to have load of buckets with a name you can vary and form the name programmatically.

Array naming is simple; an array has a name like any other variable (what I've been calling a bucket up to now - going to switch to calling them variables because everyone else does) and the name refers to the array as a whole, but the array is divided up into multiple slots all of which store the same type of data and have a unique index. Though the name of the array itself is fixed, the index can be varied; together they form a reference to  a slot within the array and provide a mechanism for having names that can be generated dynamically

```
Dim shotnames(999) as String
```

This here is an array of 1000 strings, and it's called `shotnames`. It's good to use a plural name because it helps remind you that it's an array, holding multiple something. The 999 defines the last valid slot in the array - arrays start at 0, so with this one running 0 to 999 means there are 1000 entries in it

And critically, though the `shotnames` part of the variable name remains fixed and must be what you use to refer to the array itself(if you want to do something with the entire thing, like pass it to a function), referring to an individual element/slot in the array is done by tacking a number onto the end within brackets:

```
shotnames(587) = "The 588th shotname"
```

Keep in mind that "starts at 0 thing"

This 587 can come from anything that supplies a number; it doesn't have to be hard coded by you when you write the program:

```
For i = 0 to 999
  shotnames(i) = "The " & (i+1) & "th shotname"
Next i
```

Or things that generate numbers:

```
shotnames(DateTime.Now.Minute) = "X"
```

If it's 12:59 when this code runs, then `shotnames(59)`, the sixtieth slot in the array, will become filled with `X`

There are other kinds of varying storage; a list or a dictionary are commonly used examples, but they follow these same notions - you'll get a variable where part of the name is fixed and part of the name is an index you can vary.

At their heart they are just arrays too- if you looked inside a List you'd find an array with some extra code surrounding it that, when the array gets full, it makes a new array of twice the size and copies everything over. This way it provides "an array that expands" type functionality - something that arrays don't do natively.

Dictionaries are worth mentioning because they provide a way to index by other things than a number and can achieve storage of a great number of things not known at design time as a result:

```
Dim x as New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
```

This creates a dictionary indexed by a string that stores objects (I.e. anything - dates, strings, numbers, people..)

You could do like:

```
x("name") = "John"
x("age") = 32
```

You could even realize what you were trying to do earlier:

```
For i = 0 to 999
  x("shotname"&i) = "The " & (i+1) & "th shotname"
Next i
```

(Though you'd probably do this in a Dictionary(Of string, string), ie a dictionary that is both indexed by string and stores strings.. and you probably wouldn't go to this level of effort to have a dictionary that stores `x("shotname587")` when it's simpler to declare an array `shotname(587)`)

But the original premise remains true: your variable has a fixed part of the name (ie `x`) and a changeable part of the name (ie the string in the brackets) that is used as an index.

And there is no magic to the indexing by string either. If you opened up a dictionary and looked inside it, you'd find an array, together with some bits of code that take the string you passed in as an index, and turn it into a number like 587, and store the info you want in index 587. And there is a routine to deal with the case where two different strings both become 587 when converted, but other than that it's all just "if you want a variable where part of the name is changeable/formable programmatically rather than by the developer, it's an array"