# so this is the same question as last time but i have tried an array this time still not working

Tags: vb.net

i want there to be a new variable name for every new shot, the shot name should be shot1 , shot2 up to 1000

```
Dim shotlist(1000) As Boolean

Sub Main()
    For i As Integer = 0 To 1000
        Dim istring As String = i.ToString
        shotlist(i) = "shot" & istring
    Next
End Sub
```

Any help would be great thanks

Comment: As you mentioned, isn't this at its core the same inquiry you're making in your earlier question [i want to make a new variable that says shot1 shot2 shot3 so on and forth how do i do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67084887/i-want-to-make-a-new-variable-that-says-shot1-shot2-shot3-so-on-and-forth-how-do) Why not just edit that one? Or at the very least, respond to the commenters who were so kind to try and assist you there...?

Comment: Did you notice that you're attempting to assign a string to a Boolean?

Answer (score 0):

You just assigned String ( i.e., istring ) to a Boolean ( i.e., shotlist(i) ), i hope this helps now.